# FilteringSelect text alignment

Tags: dojo

Using Dojo 1.6.1

I have a FilteringSelect that looks like:

[image]

When an address is selected, it looks like:

[image]

What I'd really like to see instead is:

[image]

Any ideas on how this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you select a value in a Filtering select, the caret position is at the end of the text, so it's not CSS that will help you there.
You have to move the cursor to the beginning of the text.

I see no other option than javascript here.

If you look at the template of dijit.form.FilteringSelect, you will see that the input node is bound to the property "focusNode" of the widget. So you could use that to move the caret, like this :

```
dijit.byId('your_filteringSelect_id').onChange = function(evt) {
    this.focusNode.setSelectionRange(0,0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an IE & FF issue see this listed bug:

http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/8298

and also this test case (issue seen in IE7-9):

http://jsfiddle.net/snover/96Ud8/

The work around suggested is to set the function _setCaretPos to do notthing e.g

```
dijit.byId('your_filteringSelect_id')._setCaretPos = function() {};
```

Answer (score 0):

.setSelectionRange doesn't work at IE

Use **dijit.selectInputText(widget.focusNode,0,0);** instead